# java.lang.runtimeexception java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Tags: java, javascript, applet, runtimeexception

I have a Javascript program that call a Java program via Applet with the following command inside the Applet:

```
script.code = "InJava.class";
```

It was necessary to make a change in the Java program, and now it creates two classes:   `InJava.class` and `InJava$1.class`

Now, when I run the program in Javascript, **the program does not answer anything**.

If I change the statement to:

```
script.code = "InJava$1.class"
```

It returns the following error:

```
runtimeexceptionjava.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception
```

How must I stated in the Javascript program?

Must I change something in my Java program?

The Java program is below:

### Java Program

```
public void sayHello() throws IOException {
  java.io.FileInputStream fis =  AccessController.doPrivileged(new   PrivilegedAction<FileInputStream>() {
  public FileInputStream run() {
     try {
          return new FileInputStream(parametro);
      } catch (IOException e)  {
          String retorno_exc = e.toString();
      }
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: An `InvocationTargetException` should have a cause - look at that for more details... and please edit your question to format your code more readably. (Fix it until the preview looks how you want it to look, basically.)

Comment: Hi you should add the stack trace to your exception